# Using absolute import while in developing Python modules?

Tags: python, python-import

I know relative imports are not suggested, such as quoted from [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged.
>   Always use the absolute package path for all imports. Even now that
>   [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) is fully implemented in Python 2.5, its style of explicit
>   relative imports is actively discouraged; absolute imports are more
>   portable and usually more readable.

What if I am developing a package (with several modules)? While in development, absolute import won't work w/o installing/deploying the package. Does that mean I have to periodically install/deploy the current WIP modules just for testing?

Here is an example provided by [Cld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973130/cld). Given a Python project/package:

```
myproject/
  package1/
     __init__.py
     somemodule.py
  package2/
     __init__.py
     somemodule.py
     somescript.py
main.py
```

In `main.py`, absolute-import works quite well:

```
import package1
import package2.somescript
import package2.somemodule
```

However, for modules, like `somescript.py` in package2, the following absolute-imports:

```
import package2.somemodule
import package1
```

It would raise ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package2/somescript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package2.somemodule
ImportError: No module named package2.somemodule
```

Comment: One approach you can take is to include the root of your project in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Then all your imports can be "absolute" (i.e. relative to the root of your project).

Comment: That might be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on where your 'main' file is.

if you have:

```
myproject/
  package1/
     __init__.py
     somemodule.py
  package2/
     __init__.py
     somemodule.py
     somescript.py
  main.py
```

somescript.py:

```
import package2.somemodule
import package1
```

main.py

```
import package1
import package2.somescript
import package2.somemodule
```

If you execute: *python package2/somescript.py* you get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package2/somescript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package2.somemodule
ImportError: No module named package2.somemodule
```

But if you execute *python main.py*, you get no problem.

Comment: Thanks for this clear example. Therefore, how could I handle ``absolute imports`` in sub-modules, like `somescript.py` in your example?

Comment: adding `import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)));` at the begin of `somescript.py` maybe... But really dirty...

Comment: Not a good idea because you have to comment them out when deploying, which increases the complexity of develop-test-deploy cycle.

Comment: Edit note - `main.py` should be inside `myproject/` instead of being outside of it. I have just done an edit to reflect this. Let me know if you think differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One common practice is `pip install -e /path_to_your_pkg/`, which will create a symbolic link of your package in the Python site-packages directory (not copying it as in standard install), doing so will enable:

- import your_pkg anywhere
- you can keep developing/updating your package and the installed version is always the latest

One known issue is if you are following PEP 517 and replace `setup.py` with `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml`, the `pip install -e` does not work. You need a dump `setup.py` as follows to fix this compatibility issue (still an issue in Jan 2021):

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```